# Semidirect Products of $A_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ up to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

Several posts on this site mention that the symmetric group $S_n$ is the semidirect product of $A_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  Is it true that $S_n$ is the only nontrivial semidirect product $A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$ up to isomorphism (perhaps apart from exceptional values of $n$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true due to the fact that $\mathrm{Aut}(A_n) = S_n$ via the conjugation action, with exceptions for $n = 1, 2, 3, 6$. An outline of the proof of this fact can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups).

A nontrivial semidirect product $A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$ is determined by a choice of nontrivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathrm{Aut}(A_n)$; hence we identify $\mathbb{Z}/2$ with a subgroup of $S_n$ of order $2$. Using this identification, the group law on the semidirect product is given by $(a_1, b_1)(a_2, b_2) = (a_1 b_1 a_2 b_1^{-1}, b_1 b_2)$. Hence we obtain an homomorphism $A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2 \to S_n$ by sending $(a, b) \mapsto ab$, since
$$(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2) = a_1b_1a_2b_1^{-1}b_1b_2.$$
If this homomorphism is injective, then it is clearly an isomorphism. Otherwise, it has kernel of order $2$, yielding a normal subgroup of $A_n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$ of order $2$ complimentary to $A_n$. In this case, you can show that the semidirect product is isomorphic to the direct product.

You can check that the result also holds for the case $n = 3$. As  the other answer mentions, you do get another semidirect product for $n = 6$. It clearly fails for $n = 1$, since $A_1 = S_1$, and for $n = 2$ the product is direct.

Answer (score 1):

This is true, apart from $n=6$ in which case there is a second, nonisomorphic, such product (and a further extension of order $720$). A proof of this fact is for example in Wilson's GTM text about simple groups.

Comment: For one's information, the group mentioned here is $\operatorname{PGL}(2,9)$, or $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(720,764)$. I used GAP to find that there are three semidirect products of $A_6$ and $C_2$: $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(720,k)$ for $k=763,764,766$, where $k=763$ corresponds to the $S_6$ case, and $k=766$ corresponds to a direct product. The three semidirect products are produced by $30$, $36$ and $46$ homomorphisms $C_2\to \operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ respectively.